# Android Recyclerview - How to have a different column count per row, based on child size?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need to develop a tag picker, like the one Foursquare uses for tastes, and the one Flipboard uses for "finding new topics."

I came across this library, [Foursquare-CollectionPicker](https://github.com/anton46/Foursquare-CollectionPicker/) at github.

However, it uses a linear layout, which can reduce the performance for numerous child views when scrolling.

Hence, I need to use a recyclerview. Can anyone suggest how to replicate this with a recyclerview? My problem is that for each row in the recyclerview, the column count could be different, based on the size/number of the child views in each row (tags, in this case).

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find anything useful ??

Answer (score 1):

You could use FlexboxLayoutManager in a recycler view. All you need to do is create the layout manager as below. Don't forget to add your own recyclerAdapter to the recycler view as well of course.

```
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html

https://blog.devcenter.co/unboxing-the-flexboxlayout-a7cfd125f023

Answer (score 1):

If *all you need* is a recycler view that changes the number of columns (using a standard Google provided GridLayoutManager in RecyclerView), you don't need any custom code at all.

(pseudo code)

#### Prerequisites

1. You use a RecylerView with a GridLayoutManager (import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager)
2. Your Adapter has a Type (so different viewTypes can inflate different ViewHolders).
3. You can initialize your grid Layout like:

```
private lateinit var layoutManager: GridLayoutManager
private val adapter = YourAdapter()

Activity#onCreate(...) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstance)
   setContentView(...)
   layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2) //defaults to two columns
   yourRecyclerView.layoutmanager = layoutManager //set it
   yourRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

   //Here goes the magic
}
```

#### What is the Magic?

Something like this:

```
   layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                return when (adapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                    adapter.viewTypeOneColumn -> 1
                    adapter.viewTypeTwoColumns -> 2
                    else -> -1
                }
            }
        }
```

This obviously assumes you have a "view type" (of any sort)

it can be as simple as:

```
class YourAdapter : ...  {
    internal val viewTypeOneColumn = 0
    internal val viewTypeTwoColumns = 1
     ...
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when(viewType) {
            viewTypeOneColumn -> ViewHolderForOneColumn(...)
            viewTypeTwoColumns -> ViewHolderForTwoColumns(...)
            else ->  throw IllegalArgumentException("You must supply a valid type for this adapter")
        }
    }

     override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return getItem(position).someThingThatClassifiesThem // this obviously depend on what you use to define what each item is...
    }
}
```

And that's all you really need.

I have once created a sample that does this for displaying "ads" inside a RecyclerView: You can check it here (it was updated a while ago but the code still works the same).

https://github.com/Gryzor/GridToShowAds

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own layout manager, take a look at these blogs: 
http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/building-a-recyclerview-layoutmanager-part-1/
http://simpleandstupid.com/2015/05/01/recyclerview-and-its-custom-layoutmanager/